# How to fetch the div value in a variable in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4 and i want to fetch the text inside my div, below is the code of `home.page.html`

```
<ion-item>
    <div id="Target" class="editable"  [innerHtml]="resume" contenteditable>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
     <br>
</ion-item>

<br>
<button ion-button (click)="fetch_div()">Fetch Div Value</button>
</ion-content>
```

home.page.ts

```
fetch_div(){
    //code to fetch the value of div
    var ElementClass = document.getElementById("Target").className;
    console.log("---");
    console.log(ElementClass);
}
```

On clicking the `Fetch Div Value`, I want to get the what all is written in the div, sample screenshot of div shown below:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ElementRef`,

**app.component.html :**

```
<div #test>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts :**

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild("test") testdiv: ElementRef;
// For angular 8+, @ViewChild("test", {static: false}) testdiv: ElementRef;

fetch_div(){
    console.log(this.testdiv.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    console.log(this.testdiv.nativeElement.innerText);
}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8v6mod

Comment: `export class CreateQPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild("test") testdiv: ElementRef;` expected 2 arguments but got 1

Comment: @user2828442 Did you check the demo?

Comment: Which line throws that error? Compare your code with mine and see what you have missed.

Comment: in angular 8, this worked - ` @ViewChild("test",{static: false}) testdiv: ElementRef;`

Comment: Yeah, It is different in version 8.